Reading the state of a pin at 35V using arduino at 5V
I have a gate controlled by a motorline MC2 motherboard. I want to add a distance sensor controlled by arduino so that I can give it the opening command when leaving the yard.
From what I have seen, the opening command is given on an input (PUL) that is grounded when the command is given. Otherwise, it is at 35V.
The problem is that I want to read the status of this input because the command can be given from 2 keyboards and when these are used I would like to disable the reading of the distance sensor.
I tried using an L7805CV regulator, but when I connect the input from the control board (PUL) to the IN of regulator, the opening command is given. I also tried using a 460Ω or 10KΩ limiting resistor but with the same result.
What other solution can I use in this case? Voltage divider, zener diode or something else?

I would like to disable the reading of the distance sensor ... why?

It has to do with the operation logic of the gate, irrelevant to the subject of the post.

Since the monitored input seems to have a really high input impedance, use a MOSFET to realize the same:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The selection of the MOSFET is left as an exercise to the reader.

Thanks!
I'm not an electrician by trade, I only use elementary things as a hobby.
I think a mosfet with Vgs of 40V is needed? Should this be the voltage at which it is completely ON or the maximum voltage supported?
I have the IRFZ44N in the box, but it seems that it supports a maximum Vgs of a maximum of 20V.

To be honest, my hardware development skills are rusted. But yes, a maximum Vgs of 40V sounds needed.

Thank you!
I will test this solution in weekend if i find an right mosfet.

In many cases, when interfacing a micro controller to devices operating at different voltages, an optical isolator is employed. This is especially true when noise from unknown sources (long wires or questionable power supplies) or the risk of current loops (from multiple power supplies) is a threat to expected operation.
If an optical isolator is not an option, many designers use a resistor divider followed by some type of voltage protection such as a zener diode or a stack of enough common diodes to create create a forward bias of the desired voltage.
For example the nearest integer number of silicon diodes to have a forward bias of about 5 volts is:
5.0 / 0.7 = 7.14

So 7 silicon diodes each with a forward bias of 0.7 volts will not short to ground when arranged in series until the anode of the first diode reaches 0.7 x 7 or 4.9 volts.

By using a voltage divider isn't it like putting the input of the board to ground?
In this case, an opening command would be given, exactly as it happens using the voltage regulator.
Also, if I feed the optocoupler from the 35V input, does the closing not trigger?

The input of most microprocessors are high impedance. So the 2 voltage divider resistors can be rather large. Consequently, little current will pass from the input of the voltage divider to ground. Choose resistor values high enough not to influence the control voltage. But not so high that noise will cause the processor to falsely trigger. Most optical coupler inputs are simply LEDs that will require regulation down to a maximum of only a few volts and require a few mA to turn on. You need to choose resistors (voltage divider and current limiting) to accommodate the optical coupler.

It seems to last, it's a bit complicated especially since I don't have many resistors at hand and the location where the gate is does not allow me to move frequently. I need a solution that will work from the first, not through trials.
But thanks for the suggestion!

"I need a solution that will work from the first, not through trials." The problem here is that we don't know what is inside the equipment generating what looks to be a pull up to 35 volts. It might be through a 1K ohm resistor to a 35 volt power supply. It might be through a 100K ohm resistor to a 35 volt power supply. We don't even know if the 35 volt control line can handle a few extra milliamps of current to power an optical isolator. Unless you have a schematic of the equipment, the only help we can provide will be based on a bit of experience and a lot of guessing.

i understand it is not a reproach just that these are the conditions
